Yocto build system rviz2 for ROS2
I want to discssion about cross-compile build system for rviz2,
rviz2 come from ROS2 project. and build by colcon which is an built-in build-system for ROS2. 
that is means rviz2 not compile by traditional "cmake", "automake"
In such case. How does yocto to build rviz2.?
Is yotco build an ROS2's emulation for build rviz2?
Thanks
Peter
